# Libhand library compilation error on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, ogre, libhand

I'm trying to build a hand model library from libhand.org on Ubuntu 12.04.

Unfortunately when Compiling the examples I get the following error:

```
fan@dell:~/libhand-0.9/examples/build$ make
Scanning dependencies of target bend_one_finger
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/bend_one_finger./bend_one_finger.cc.o
Linking CXX executable bend_one_finger
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreDynLib.cpp.o): undefined reference to symbol 'dlopen@@GLIBC_2.1'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'dlopen@@GLIBC_2.1' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bend_one_finger] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/bend_one_finger.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Does anyone know why this error occurs and what can be done?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You'de better close this question on SO and post it on https://askubuntu.com/